# Spring and MongoDB - How to query documents depend on the filters?

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb

I have a project that uploads/download documents, and in the metadata of this documents are in MongoDB. I'm using java spring to store the data into MongoDb. And all is fine to save, get, delete and updates.
The problem is when i try to search the documents depend on a filter.

For example, the filter can be:
Region = Europe, Country = Spain, Category = cat1

or can be just:
Region = Europe, Country = Spain

So the filters are variable, depend on the client selection. They can filter by several fields or just by one or none..

So I don't know how to do that. Because I'm using the repository and if the filter is null, they search by this null value...

For example: If category is null, because the client is not filtering by this field, mongo search the documents by category=null...
Any one can help me?

Thanks,

Comment: One way to handle this is to implement the Repository method (in a RepositoryImpl class). This repo class in turn creates a filter based upon the supplied values (series of if-then-else to check for the nulls, and build the filter), and call a MongoTemplate#find method with the filter).

Comment: Ok thanks!! i'll do that, i was thinking in something more automatically, without IFs... but ok

Comment: You can try - its just a thought. There may be a better way to do it.